# How do I monitor website and download data using nodejs services?

Tags: node.js, monitoring, watchdog

I have to make nodejs service for monitoring copernicus website and to download locally satellite pictures from exactly one place. Basically when there is new satellite picture for my spot, download it to my computer. It has to be some kind of watchdog to monitor is there new picture and then if there is new picture download it. Problem is that you have to login on website, use exactly one polygon for region of interest and to choose which satellite we are going to use, so if someone has an idea or solution how to make it please write below. Here is copernicus platform where we have to do that: https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the conditions for your query can be encoded as *query strings* in your URL. SciHub (more precisely the underlying software, DHuS), does not have any kind of notification capability, you truly need to keep querying periodically.

The URL is easy to construct. This shell command demonstrates such query: you may reuse the URL in whatever language.

```
curl -sS -n 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?q=footprint:%22Intersects(49.8139,15.6617)%22%20AND%20platformname:Sentinel-2%20AND%20producttype:S2MSI2A%20AND%20beginPosition:%5b2018-09-20T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20NOW%5d&start=0&rows=100'
```

The following attributes are interesting:

- `footprint:%22Intersects()` is the coordinates you want to search. This example gives a single point (two coordinates -- lattitude, longitude) but you can also specify polygons.
- `platformname` and `producttype` let you specify the satellite platform and type of product: in this case Sentinel 2 images with atmospheric correction applied.
- `beginPosition` is the time stamp from which to search, i.e., you need to keep updating that to query only for newer products than you already got
- `start` and `rows` are for paging. The maximum page size (`rows`) is 100, so if your answer contains more records, you need to get them page-by-page.

This is all done through the Open Search interface for DHuS, which is documented here: https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/OpenSearchAPI

The query returns an XML array of matching products. You may download full products (URLs are provided) or components thereof.